# How to change byte literal to str variable with LoRa module's send()?

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, lora

For 2 Raspberry Pi Pico's with SX126X LoRa modules attached I use [this library](https://github.com/ehong-tl/micropySX126X) and have the ping pong example working. I want to send a JSON string from one to the other. `sx.send(b'Ping')` sends `b'Ping'` to the remote device (if I remove the `b` it fails).

I want to save a JSON string to a variable and send it with `sx.send()`. The `b` is somehow required and I can't figure out how to swap literal `'Ping'` with a variable.

From main.py:

```
while True:
    sx.send(b'Ping')
    time.sleep(10)
```

SX1262.py:

```
def send(self, data):
    if not self.blocking:
        return self._startTransmit(data)
    else:
        return self._transmit(data)


def _startTransmit(self, data):
    if isinstance(data, bytes) or isinstance(data, bytearray):
        pass
    else:
        return 0, ERR_INVALID_PACKET_TYPE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `b` in `sx.send(b'Ping')` means that you are sending literal bytes, as opposed to a string. This notation is internal to Python. What is actually sent is `Ping`. And when the other device receives it, it is stored as bytes, and when displayed:

```py
>>>> packet = b'Ping'
>>>> packet
b'Ping'
>>>> len(packet)
4
```

As you can see there are only 4 bytes in `packet`.

To send a JSON string you can do something like this:

```py
>>>> import json
>>>> p = '{"name": "Bob", "languages": ["Python", "Java"]}'
>>>> j = json.loads(p)
>>>> sx.send(bytes(json.dumps(j).encode()))
```

`json.dumps(j)` takes a JSON object `j` and transforms it into a string with `dumps()`, after making sure it has an encoding (`encode()`), and turns that string into bytes. Which you can send.

On the other side, on device 2, you can just `json.loads()` the bytes to make it a JSON object.

Getting the values back to variables is easy:

```py
>>>> j['name']
'Bob'
>>>> j['languages']
['Python', 'Java']
```